# Is it possible to install Safari extension for all users?

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension

I'm looking for a solution to install extension from a script that will be available for all users. Could you suggest something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as it would be a security issue to allow extensions to be installed without user consent (see what's been happening recently with firefox and unwanted extension installation).  You could file a bug a http://bugreport.apple.com but I suspect that anything that allows global extension installation could be used to allow unwanted/silent installation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe so.
And don't try to do it. It's a unsecured idea.

Comment: I understand that, but my customer wants the extension to work this way.

Comment: Yes, same here. My clients want the similar thing. Their IT will install My Excel AddIn for them and they want the AddIn available to all users on a PC.  and they want silent installation.  Originally I thought I can add registry entry for each user. However, I find some users' entries are simply not shown up.  So this is not a solution. What else can I try? thanks